# Parsear xml largo con php

Tags: php, xml

Eh estado intentando parsear un xml que esta guardado en el servidor para poder sacar un dato y poder guardarlo en una variable, uso este sencillo codigo:

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/html2pdf/xml.xml';
$xmltoprint=simplexml_load_file($file);
var_dump($xmltoprint);
```

El problema es que no lo parsea completo, llega solo a un cuarto de lo que es. el archivo pesa si mucho 12kb,  hay alguna otra funcion que haga lo que necesito o hay alguna forma de sacar el dato directamente?, el que necesito es un campo timestamps.

Comment: 12kb no es un fichero largo ni mucho menos. 12megas tampoco lo sería.
Me parece mñas que es un problema de que habrá algún carácter raro, una comilla, doble comilla, algún símbolo... que cuando el parser llega ahí es cuando no puede continuar

Comment: Quita el `var_dump`, al hacerlo sobre un objeto de `simplexml_load_file` muchas veces suele acabar en recursividad que se come toda la memoria.